# ngOptions applied twice in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive that replaces a normal a select tag with a customized one:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('mySelect', function() {
 return {
   restrict: 'AE',
   require: 'ngModel',
   templateUrl: 'mySelect.html'
   replace: true,
   scope: true,
   controller: ['$scope', function($scope) { $scope.options = [1,2,3,4,5] }],
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      // No updates to scope here
   }
 }
});
```

And the template looks like:

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="(x | sprintf:'%02d') for x in options"></select>
```

For some strange reason, the options created by `ng-options` are applied twice. The resulting HTML looks like:

```
<select my-select ng-options="(x | sprintf:'%02d') for x in options" class="...">
  <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="0">01</option>
  <option value="1">02</option>
  <option value="2">03</option>
  <option value="3">04</option>
  <option value="4">05</option>
  <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="0">01</option>
  <option value="1">02</option>
  <option value="2">03</option>
  <option value="3">04</option>
  <option value="4">05</option>
</select>
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Try defining $scope.options inside link, rather than controller.

Comment: @ZackArgyle, defining options in the link function had no impact.

Comment: @bibs Can't reproduce. http://jsfiddle.net/h83vT/

Comment: @sza, your fiddle is slightly different from my example. I tweaked your fiddle (see: http://jsfiddle.net/3j5C9/) and noticed that angular is printing an error in the console that it isn't printing on my machine: `Error: Multiple directives [select, select] asking for 'select' controller on: <select ng-options="x for x in options" ng-model="value" my-select="">`. Using the directive as an element rather than an attribute on an existing <select> solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use div instead of `<select my-select></select>` like this

```
<div my-select></div>
```

The directive `mySelect` return another `select` directive so you will get the error `Error: Multiple directives [select, select]` because the HTML will be rendered as

```
<select ng-options="x for x in options" ng-model="value" my-select=""></select>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3j5C9/1/)**</kbd>